# What SMD is "A40" and "SB"?

Tags: identification, surface-mount

Here are some images of a little LED "backlight" board. It just lights two (red) high-intensity LEDs.  There are two ICs on it which could use some identification help please.

- 2.00mm square package, marked "SB", three pads.  Assume MOSFET. Can see a diode in it towards the left LED below.
- 3.00 x 1.50mm package, perhaps a Micro6, marked "A40".  Assume CC LED driver.  Most likely this failed.

Any chance someone has an idea what these are?

[image: Top]

[image: Bottom]
Orange = 220µF caps (parallel.)

[image: Micro1]

Apologies for the awful 'scope bloom.

[image: Micro2]

Note on measuring this A40 (in-circuit):

- Pins 2-1, 2-3, 2-5, and 2-6 all show slightly different ~0.6V diode-drops.
- Ditto for pins 4-1, 4-3, 4-5, and 4-6.
- Pins 2,4 must be power. They go across the top-right three caps in parallel (including the two orange caps on back.) Guess they were serious about bypass!

**EDIT** - I found another, slightly different board. This one still has the same "SB" 3-terminal device (all three pins are used), but the "A40" is replaced with an "AAUW":

[image: Back2]

[image: Front2a]

[image: Front2b]

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bottom of the two is a SOT23-6 package (3 x 1.5mm, 6-pin).

With the marking code, that could indicate something like an [OPA363](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa364.pdf) Operational Amplifier for TI. Does seem odd, but the pinout matches fairly well. Not entirely sure what it's doing in the circuit though.

[image: Texas Instruments OPA363]

---

From the update of a second board, AAUW is again as SOT23-6 package, this time a Maxim Integrated [MAX4237EUT](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX4236-MAX4237.pdf) device. This is also a single channel op-amp with the same pinout, so that suggests that the TI part is correct.

Comment: Yeah, it's odd. On that board I'd expect a smps ic of sorts. Especially considering the two large caps. But no inductor of a size suggested by the size of the "SB" diode in sight... A charge pump?

Comment: Aaah no, I think I get it! The smps is off-board somewhere else, but the current sense resistor (0.200 Ohm) is here. This is a measurement amplifier for current feedback.

Comment: @mmm That'd do it!

Comment: I'd been trying to trace the board, but it's a 4-layer construction.

Comment: Maybe used to turn LED driving from PWM to analog?

Answer (score 1):

The "A40" part could be a [OPA363AIDBVT](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/opa364). The "SB" part looks like a [SBS007M](https://www.digchip.com/datasheets/download_datasheet.php?id=854994&part-number=SBS007M)